# static interfaces in c#

Tags: c#, interface

Sorry it's possibly a duplicate but in the other static interface they mention generics which I am not using.

I wanted a quick and simple logger for my app I though I could avoid a singleton using a static element.
I would have like to keep the interface so that later I could change to another logging package. The interface being for me (I may be wrong here) a way to implement a "facade" feature.

I have the feeling I am overlooking something.
A gentle push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. (Hope it's a bit clearer)

```
public interface Ilogger
{
    void Log(string data, out DateTime datetime, out string uid);
}

public class Logger : Ilogger
{
    private static TraceSource AppTrace = new TraceSource("RD", SourceLevels.All);

    static Logger ()
    {
       AppTrace.Listeners.Clear();
       AppTrace.Listeners.Add(new DelimitedListTraceListener("RD.log"));
    }

    static void Log(string data, out DateTime datetime, out string uid)
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        AppTrace.TraceInformation(datetime + ";" + uid + ";" + data);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, or where "static interfaces" would come into play... Please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: You guys are quick on the trigger! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to combine a singleton with a facade. Sort of a service locator. i.e. create a singleton that got the same methods as your interface and then assign the interface to the facade as the singleton.

[I've blogged about it](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/07/a-less-evil-singleton/).

Comment: Thanks Jgauffin, that's what I wrote at first. but then thought it would simplified the situation if I just used a static method. So there is no others (simpler) way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support static inheritance or static interface implementation. static variables *are* just a form of a Singleton either way you look at it - just go with a Singleton or better use a DI container to inject the logger dependency.